# Java: Why can a file not have more than one public class

Tags: java

```
public class A
{
}  

public class B 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    }
}
```

Why cant we declare both class as public?
Why only `Main` class  can be public?
i know that by making class public ,it will allow you access in package ok ,but what if i make

```
     public    class a
     { 

     }
    class B
     {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

     }
  }
```

why this code give error
 do we really need to notify that  main class is public bcoz every class is public

Comment: A public class requires saving with the same file name as the class name.

Comment: but by default every class is public ..

Comment: No by default, a class is applied *no modifier* which is different in nature from public.

Answer (score 4):

Because one .java file can contain only one public class.

If you want these two classes to be public they have to be put into two .java files: `A.java` and `B.java`.

From the [JLS 7.6. Top Level Type Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler to find a named class within a package. In practice, many programmers choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other compilation units.

Comment: but by default every class in java is public ..so is it really important to mention it..and if,then why they said so..

Comment: Not every class in java is public by default.  They are package-private by default

Comment: thanks guys it realy helps...:)

Comment: no if we put the package thing apart  then what will happen,,

Comment: @user2461247 : How do you *put the package thing apart*? A Java class is always inside a package even though you don't mention so. In which case, it uses a default package.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @DonLarynx Then write your own answer.

Comment: to be more specific, your answer uses circular reasoning. Why cant we have more than one public class? Because we cant. You beg the question.

Answer (score 2):

The filename for a Java class is the public class' name. You cannot have 2 file names, hence you cannot have 2 public classes.