# Does every Java .class file contain a public class?

Tags: java, contains, .class-file

I got a question on an exam.

Does every **.class** (not .java) file contain a public class?

Yes? No?

Comment: are you doing a test exam right now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5204385/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/16971610/1531971 https://www.coursehero.com/file/p1e2uc8/Format-of-a-Java-Program-Every-Java-file-contains-a-public-class-interface-or/

Comment: @ValentinRuano No, Im just curious, I chose "no".

Comment: This question is not mean for SO ... we expect that you actually try to answer it yourself and if you get stuck then we may come in and help... usually you would have some code, command line or something that you include in your question.... you question does not show that you even try.... more like drop/dump it and see what happens. Google it first, try it yourself... eg. what if you try to compile a non-public class containing .java doesn't the compiler creates a .class file? is a simple like that to find the answer, right?

Comment: This is the reason why question like yours a suspect of someone that have a homework and they do want to bother to do (or don't have the time) or is in a exam room looking for a quick fix... not that that is necessarily your case but it simply looks like it ... and often is in fact the case. This is more obvious with homework though.

Answer (score 2):

No,
can have some classes as private, protected, default and public. From these four type

Answer (score 1):

No, class files are generated (also) for less visible and even "inner" classes.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there are 4 different types:

- Public
- Private
- Protected
- Default

Answer (score 0):

No access modifiers include `public`, `protected`, and `private`.

Example:

`public class foo {}`

`private class foo {}`

`protected class foo {}`

You can also have a class without an access modifier.

`class foo {}`

However, if you want to be able to fully access your class from another class use the `public` access modifier.

See here for more information : [Examining Class Modifiers and Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classModifiers.html)